# Буфферизированные и небуфферизированные запросы в базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Я слышал о двух видах запросов: буфферизированный и небуфферизированный, буфферизированный запрос заключается в том что результат запроса к бд целиком копируется в память приложения( а именно копируется в память библиотеки которую использует приложение для общения с базой данных ), а небуфферизированный запрос не копирует результат в память приложения, а остается на стороне базы данных и вытаскивается приложением по мере необходимости.

1) В чем достоинства и недостатки этих двух подходов? В случае с буфферизированным запросом недостаток более менее понятен,  он просто потребляет большой объем оперативной памяти при больших результирующих наборах, а что насчет небуфферизированного запроса, в чем его недостаток?

2) Какие базы данных поддерживают небуфферизированный запрос? Я знаю только одну базу данных: Mysql, но может есть другие субд поддерживающие небуфферизированные запросы?

Comment: *что насчет небуфферизированного запроса, в чем его недостаток?* Блокирование соединения - это стопроцентно. А также - проблемы с перемещением по набору данных, недостоверность сведений о полном количестве записей.

Comment: Akina, а остальные соединения буду блокироваться в этот момент, к примеру у нас много поточное приложение в котором работают несколько клиентов, клиент 1 решил запросить данные при помощи небуферизированного запроса, будет ли  клиент 2 в этом случае  иметь доступ к тем же данным(к примеру к той же таблице), не будут ли блокироваться запросы клиента 2 к той же таблице, пока клиент 1 делает свою работу?

Comment: Нет. Это соединение невозможно использовать. Если нужно выполнить ещё один запрос - придётся использовать другое соединение. Что может вызвать сложности, например, при использовании временных таблиц и пользовательских переменных.

Comment: Запросы второго клиента не будут блокироваться по чтению, но по записи могут быть заблокированы, если об этом попросил первый клиент, когда начинал читать (см. select for update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Практически все современные СУБД поддерживают небуферизованные запросы. И для большинства из них это совершенно обычный режим работы. Буферизацию всех данных на клиенте обычно драйвера делают по отдельному запросу.

Конкретно в MySQL этот механизм реализован так, что его использование возможно довольно редко. Проблема состоит в том, что в рамках одного соединения одновременно могут передаваться данные только одного запроса. Из за этого во время выполнения небуферизированого запроса вы не можете быстро обратиться к той же БД за какой нибудь другой информацией, а потом опять вернутся к чтению из первого запроса.

В других СУБД (Posgresql, Oracle, MS SQL) этот механизм реализован и гораздо лучше, чем в MySQL. У них на уровне драйвера даже не надо переключать режим работы, потому что по умолчанию он уже находится в небуферизированном состоянии. Большинству драйверов вы можете задать объем данных, которые драйвер может заранее получать от сервера и хранить в своих буферах. В получении же всех данных за один раз надобности нет вообще. Потому, что эти БД могут одновременно держать открытыми несколько запросов в рамках одного соединения и помнить по каждому запросу на чем они остановились. Правда в большинстве случаев все эти запросы будут выполнятся в рамках одной транзакции. Если транзакция находится в режиме согласованного чтения, то все эти запросы будут видеть одни и те же данные на момент начала их выполнения. Что касается блокировок ресурсов в таком состоянии, то в каждой СУБД они решаются по своему.